# Creating a carousel that accesses API data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, carousel

I'm a relative newby to writing Javascript code and I'm trying to create a webpage that can display upcoming films, accessing an API for the data I need. I've been able to successfully display the images and text I want from the API on my browser and now I want to create a carousel for those images. I've tried to create a function that can do this which will then be passed down. I'm having trouble organising my page so that the function is invoked and then accessible within the existing set-up I've written. My code is below. Any advice on how best to set this up within the page and link the two so it executes correctly would be great.

-------CODE BELOW ---------

```
import React from "react";

const HomePage = (props) => {

  let carouselSlider = 0;

const showSlides = () => {
      let i;
      let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("carouselData");
      for (i= 0; i <slides.length; i ++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      carouselSlider++;
      if (carouselSlider > slides.length) {carouselSlider =1}
      slides[carouselSlider -1].style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
  };

  showSlides()

    return (
        <div className="search">
        <input
            placeholder="search for a film"
            onChange={(event) => props.setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={() => props.apiFetch(props.searchTerm)}>
            Click to search for a film
        </button>


        <div className="carousel-container">
          {props.movieData?.length > 0
              ?(
  
                 props.movieData.map((movie)=>(
                  <div className="carouselData" key={movie.id}>
                   <h3>{movie.originalTitleText.text}</h3>
                    <div className="carouselImage">
                      <img alt="filmImage" src={movie.primaryImage !== null ?      movie.primaryImage.url : "https://via.placeholder.com/400"}
                          style={{transform:`translateX(-${carouselSlider * 100}%)`}}/>
                    </div>

                 
                   </div>
                 ))
                  
             ) : (
               <h2>No Movies found</h2>
             )
  
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default HomePage;
```

I've tried to write the function in another file and invoke it elsewhere to keep my code organised but I struggled to achieve a connection between my pages.